# Copypaste multiple rows and columns, but change data of the first column only

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have a template for one shop, that I need to copy but change only the first column, based on list of shops I can provide. The number of shops and number of items can change multiple times a week. So I end up with 10k number of rows, and at the moment I just copypaste manually and change shop name every x number of rows. I would like to automate this process, so I can make a template for one shop, provide names of other shops, and it will copy the rows and columns of first shop to all other shops.

| shop | item | promo start | promo end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alpha | a | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| alpha | b | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| alpha | c | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| alpha | d | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |

Now, I have another x number of shops, like beta, charlie, delta, echo, etc and I need the sheet to look like this

| shop | item | promo start | promo end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alpha | a | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| alpha | b | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| alpha | c | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| alpha | d | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| beta | a | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| beta | b | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| beta | c | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| beta | d | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| charlie | a | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| charlie | b | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| charlie | c | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| charlie | d | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| delta | a | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| delta | b | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| delta | c | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |
| delta | d | 15.11.2021 | 20.11.2021 |

Because there can be 40 shops with 150 items each, that is thousands of rows I do manually.

Is there a way Excel can do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in PowerQuery, not VBA. Example file attached. Just update the template and shoplist and hit the Data > Refresh all button. The result will be in the Final sheet.

You can add as many columns/lines as you want in the template but keep the "shop" column blank.
In the shop list you can only add rows and you must keep the merge column blank.

[Merge shoplist based on template](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmi1wp8n71swhp4/ShopsTemplate.xlsx?dl=0)

If you want to see the code used go to menu Data > Queries and connections > right click any query in the new pane and choose edit.

Comment: Unbelievable, thank you very much! You have saved me a great deal of time!